# Show that $s(x) = t(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $s, t : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions and suppose $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $\overline{D}=\mathbb{R}$ ). Suppose that $s(x) = t(x)$ for every $x \in D$. Show that $s(x) = t(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

This is what I was thinking...

Suppose that $s(x) = t(x)$, $\forall x \in D$ and let $x'$ denote the set of limit points of $D$. Now choose $x' \in x/D$ and any sequence $\lbrace x_n \rbrace \subset D$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x'$. Then continuity guaranties that $t(x_n) \rightarrow t(x')$ and $s(x_n) \rightarrow s(n)$. But $s(x_n) = t(x_n)$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, therefore the limit must be the same. So, $s(x')=t(x')$.

Is this how you would correctly prove this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the proof is correct, I am writing it clearly here

For every point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is a sequence$\{x_n\}\in D$ that converges to $x$.  So $s(x_n),t(x_n)$ converges to $s(x)$ and $t(x)$ respectively but $s(x)=t(x)$ as $s(x_n)=t(x_n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.